# How to mount top-level directory using NFS and fstab

Tags: macos, mount, nfs

My setup on macOS consists of the following:

- The `/etc/synthetic.conf` file contains the line: `mydata`.
- A directory `/mydata` was created.
- The `/etc/fstab` file contains the line: `myserver:/exports/mydata /mydata nfs resvport`

I **can** mount this directory now by running `sudo mount -a`, however I would like this directory to be mounted **on startup or bootup of the system**. I expected this setup to automatically mount this directory on bootup, but it does not. Also, I didn't see any service that might assist. So my question: can I use `/etc/fstab` with NFS mounts mounting on bootup or do I have use some other technology in macOS?

Note that I'm not using `auto_nfs`, just basic `/etc/fstab` and static mounts. I'm not opposed to using `automount`, I just would like to know if I can make my current setup work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The mount may be failing because the network is not yet up and running when file systems are mounted (at least, that's my experience in Linux). You may want to specify `bg` as an option to keep trying the mount in the background: `myserver:/exports/mydata /mydata nfs resvport,bg` (see `man mount_nfs` for details).

Comment: In the bootup sequence, I think the key option is `net`, which tells the system to delay the mount attempt until the network is running (this option also works in linux). `bg` and `soft` are also useful for retry conditions: `myserver:/exports/mydata /mydata nfs resvport,bg,soft,net`